# How to write arrays to .bson file using bson package from pymongo

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, pymongo, bson

I have a dictionary `my_dict` of the following form. It has two keys, `'0'` and `'1'`. For either of these keys, `my_dict['0']` is an `np.array` with `np.shape(my_dict['0']) = (10, 400000)`.

I am trying to use the `bson` package from PyMongo to write this dictionary to a .bson file. My code is

```
import bson

with open('file_name.bson', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bson.encode(my_dict))
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidDocument                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [58], line 2
      1 with open('file_name.bson', 'wb') as f:
----> 2     f.write(bson.encode(my_dict))

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bson/__init__.py:1021, in encode(document, check_keys, codec_options)
   1018 if not isinstance(codec_options, CodecOptions):
   1019     raise _CODEC_OPTIONS_TYPE_ERROR
-> 1021 return _dict_to_bson(document, check_keys, codec_options)

InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: array([[-6.23719836e+02, -1.36955615e+03, -2.26481493e+03, ...,
        -2.57530488e+05,  1.41191655e+05,  3.68818106e+05],
       [ 3.51672758e+03,  4.23929871e+03,  4.19956936e+03, ...,
        -1.36596353e+07,  2.86662539e+06,  1.44995899e+07],
       [-6.13804894e+03, -3.91523214e+03, -4.16903017e+03, ...,
        -4.40730152e+08,  9.73392618e+07,  4.49351728e+08],
       ...,
       [-2.28620787e+04,  3.11671441e+04, -5.07810896e+04, ...,
        -1.30874776e+15,  7.45906067e+14,  1.16835974e+15],
       [-1.70260327e+05,  4.86525723e+04, -2.65229256e+05, ...,
        -1.91624806e+16,  1.20260881e+16,  1.67045997e+16],
       [-8.67528180e+05,  5.10548548e+04, -1.18028366e+06, ...,
        -2.62114048e+17,  1.77851766e+17,  2.23740879e+17]]), of type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

It seems like .bson is struggling with the array structure? This is very odd because I've definitely imported arrays from .bson files before though.

I've been trying to google to see what is going on with this `InvalidDocument` error but haven't found anything useful yet.

The closest is [this site](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20BSON%20document%20size,MongoDB%20provides%20the%20GridFS%20API.) which says the max BSON doc size is 16 MB, but I really don't think my arrays have this issue / I've definitely imported way larger arrays from .bson before

If anyone can give me a pointer, or even just point me towards a gentle page describing how to write a .bson file (I've realy struggled to find a good reference for easy file I/O with `bson`), please let me know!

Comment: What is `my_dict['0'].nbytes`?

Comment: ChatGPT seems to suggest switching to lists (avoiding np.arrays altogether)

Comment: Does using `bson.encode({k[0]: [list(n) for n in k[1]] for k in my_dict.items()})` work for you?  It's not difficult to convert between numpy arrays and lists, but note that the number of bytes is much higher than 16M, so I'm not sure if you can store it in MongoDB - `bson.encode` seems to work with this size though.